# Stone surround repair advice

Tags: repair, fireplace, stone

[image][image]

We have a stone surround to our fireplace. I have noticed stone/cement dust often around it. about a week ago this stone came loose when my son hit it with a toy car. I have now noticed at least one more loose stone. This surround goes up to the ceiling and I want to fix this and strengthen stone that has not yet loosened. I am not sure what to use and should I first remove all old cement? 
Thank you [image]

Comment: Is the dust fine like flour or coarse like bread crumbs?

Answer (score 1):

I would not remove any of the cement, except for vacuuming and brushing to make sure the surfaces are clean so the stone can be glued back in place with construction adhesive. Keep the glue far from the edges so it does not show, should any try to squeeze out. Prop it in place until the glue dries, a day or two will do and it will stay.

Comment: If it’s “real” stone and is over my head, (goes up to the ceiling,) I’d want to know if all that “cement dust” is unique or signs of a trend...especially because she says there’s another one loose.

Comment: This all depends on the texture of the dust. If it is very coarse, like  chunks the size of bread crumbs and larger, it will be from the vibration of the toy or other repeated hit from something, whether it be from a vacuum cleaner or other random objects. In this case, timing is everything when this type of wall is built. When the cement is added to the wall to apply the stone, the longer it sits on the wall before the stone is applied, the weaker the bond. So most stones will be bonded well but a few may not. Vibration is the enemy of all masonry. No room to comment about finer dust here.

Comment: If a chid can hit the masonry and knock a piece loose, I don’t want to be near it. So you think the “dust” is from the mortar?

Comment: I am certain the dust is from the mortar. When this material is installed, the whole wall is covered in tar paper, or should be, then expanded metal lath and skim coated with masonry cement everywhere the cast stone goes and left to set up overnight. The wall gets another coat before the stone goes on and the cast stone is stuck onto it. There are variations of the this method, but that is the gist of it. Long story short, the whole wall is covered in mortar (cement).

Comment: The nature of the dust will or may reveal a little more info, I have a question to the OP and her answer may fill in more details, should I get an answer...

Comment: That’s a faux stone veneer wall...look at the piece that came loose. It looks like the veneer stone was improperly installed (embedded) into the “mortar”. I call this kind of installation a “scratch coat”. If you look closely at the next stone above, it’s cracking loose too. I think either 1) the scratch coat was improperly mixed, and/or 2) they waited too long before pressing the stone into the mix. Bad installation. I’d expect more to come loose.

Comment: The dust is fine like flour, the stone is real or I believe it is but it’s like they are broken in half. There are a couple large chunks. This was built we believe 15 years ago

Comment: I’ve added a new picture to help you see behind this stone. I have cleaned up fine dust several times from around the area since we moved in, in June.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to be a fine dust. What I see in the new picture is what I expected, coarse crumbs with smaller crumbs and the fine dust like you mentioned. The stone is a colored concrete and on the backside usually there are "comb" marks that are made while the concrete is still wet to allow the setting mortar to grip into these marks.

Comment: Do you think this indicates a bigger problem?

Comment: As Lee Sam mentioned, there may be a few more that are, or may become loose. It has been there for 15 years, and mortar does not degrade in a protected environment. The ones at the bottom where they get struck on occasion will be the most likely ones to release. The rest of the wall should not be a problem. I do not consider it a big problem. The ones that you see that are suspect could be lightly tapped on with a rubber mallet to see if they finish coming loose. The ones with the hairline cracks around the edges are the most likely to do so. Ones that have none should not be an issue ever...